# Printing multiple values mysql without adding them

Tags: mysql, session

Let's say I have:

```
set @a = 1;
set @contents = @a;

set @a = 2;
set @contents = "Contents is " @contents + "," + @a;
```

Where I want to have it display : "Contents is 1,2"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

You can use it like this:

```
set @a = 1;
set @contents = @a;

set @a = 2;
set @contents = concat("Contents is ", @contents, ",", @a);
```